# How do I confirm sqlite3 is properly loaded and running?

Tags: php, apache, sqlite

I had a friend configure my server for sqlite3 yesterday.

He went in through putty and used a command line to determine if it was already installed:

```
locate sqlite3
```

it came back that it was indeed located as this shows:

```
/usr/bin/sqlite3
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib64/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_sqlite3-1.so
/usr/lib64/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_sqlite3.so
/usr/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1.gz
/usr/share/rails/configs/databases/sqlite3.yml
```

So then he proceeded to explain how we had to configure the apache to recognize and load that module.  So we went into the httpd/conf.d/ directory and vi edited the php_conf file by adding this line <<---THIS LINE & now the complete file looks like this:

```
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

LoadModule php5_module modules/pdo_sqlite.so<<---THIS LINE

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
```

We then saved that file (i just double checked). We then called /etc/init.d/httpd reload and then restart.  We got Green OKs all around.

But I still get:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found
```

when calling this line in my php file:

```
$db = new SQLite3($sqlite_database);
```

Any ideas how else I could test to see what is wrong?

Comment: `SQLite3` != `PDO_SQLITE`

Comment: Ok can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: SQLite3 is be enabled by default since PHP 5.3.0. Either you are using an older version, or it was disabled when compiling PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php

Comment: Ok how do I re-enable it from an ssh terminal?

Comment: Only by compiling PHP again …

Comment: Is that complicated? How is it done?

Comment: That’s to broad to be answered here in short. Go do some research, or get a server admin who knows their stuff.

Comment: Well the configure command says --without sqlite and --without sqlite3 but I can see an additional sqlite.ini file parsed and pro drivers as well as pro_sqlite drivers enabled

Comment: _“pro drivers”_ – you mean PDO drivers? Well that’s all fine, but your script _is not using_ the PDO driver to communicate with SQLite …

Comment: So I definitely have to recompile?